# Divide a matrix - How to do that in MATLAB?

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-equations

I want to write out this formula

$$P = P - P\phi(I+\phi^TP\phi)^{-1}\phi^TP$$

I tried this matlab code:

```
P = P - P*phi*inv(I + phi'*P*phi)*phi'*P;
```

But it didn't work.

Then I tried this and it work.

```
P = P - (P*phi*phi'*P)/(I + phi'*P*phi);
```

The dimensions are following:

$P\in \Re^{nxn},$
$\phi\in \Re^{nx1},$
$\theta\in \Re^{nx1}$

So what is the right interpretation to the formula?

If you wonder what formula it is. Have a look at equation 5 in this document:

[Recursive Least Square](http://www.it.uu.se/edu/course/homepage/empmod/ht12/FR.pdf)

Or equation 2.17 in this document, page 51:

[Adaptive Control](http://www.ioe.nchu.edu.tw/Pic/CourseItem/4775_Astrom%20-%20Adaptive%20Control_Part1.pdf)

Comment: What error did the inv version give?

Comment: @Ian It gave me: error: test: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 4x1, op2 is 4x4)
error: called from
    test at line 36 column 5

Comment: Surely you can be more descriptive than "it didn't work". By the way, you have a minus sign inside your inverse in the formula that has become a plus sign in your code.

Comment: Well, yeah, that is indeed a problem with your formula, you are trying to multiply a 4x1 vector with a 4x4 matrix in that order. Maybe you meant $(P\phi)^T$ at the front of the product?

Comment: @Ian Sorry! I change that sign now. No. I don't meant $(P\phi)^T$. I try to do exactly as the url link "Adaptive control" says.

Comment: Well, $\phi^T P\phi$ is $1\times1$, and it seems that all dimensions match. If matlab complains about the big expression, try smaller pieces of it first. This might give you an idea what is going wrong and why. For example, what is I, here? I don't know much matlab. Does it infer the size of I from context?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: There isn't *one* identity matrix. There is one for each $n$, of size $n\times n$. In this case, it has to be the $1\times1$ identity, right?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You solve the problem! It wasin't $I$ as identity matrix. It was $1$ as a number one. I don't know why the book "Adaptive Control" write a $I$ there.

Comment: Perhaps $\phi$ could more generally be $n\times k$? Then it makes sense to write $I$.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen According to the book, $\phi$ is a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
q = [2, 4; 6, 8] * inv([1, 2; 3, 4]
```

Where `inv` is the inverse function, `q` is the new matrice, and the two matrices are what matrices is left division going to happen upon.